# Triple screen desktop

Tags: nvidia, xorg, multiple-monitors

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and I want to have a triple monitor setup for the desktop.

Here are my GPU cards :

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF110 [GeForce GTX 580] (rev a1)
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GT218 [GeForce 210] (rev a2)
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF110 [GeForce GTX 580] (rev a1)
```

The two GTX 580 are bridged in SLI to drive the center screen only (for 120Hz gaming in Win8), and the G 210 drives the two 19" for extended desktop.

Here are my monitors

```
Samsung 27" 1920x1080 (center)
Acer 19" 1280x1024 (right)
Bluesky 19" 1280x1024 (left)
```

I've activated proprietary nVidia drivers (version 319) and tried to use the "nVidia X Server Settings" to get the same config as under Win8, but no luck :(

The closest result i achieved was using separate x-screens on each monitor, but i'm unable to move windows from a monitor to an other.

On one side, each time i try to enable Xinerama, it fails to restart X and i have to restore the default xorg.conf (seems it's due to different GPUs)

On the other side, i can only enable TwinView on side sreens, as they are on the same GPU.

So my question is simple : how can i have a triple monitor setup with my hardware ?
I can't beleive all linux users with triple screens run with two identical GPU.

I'm ready to change any software part (kernel, driver, WM ...) but i have to keep the same hardware configuration (one 120hz screen on 580 SLI, rest on 210) for windows gaming.

Comment: I run 4 displays off of 3 ATI/AMD based video cards. Primary is a higher-end card runs 2 displays, other 2 are less powerful PCIe x1 cards and drive one display each. Obviously different GPU, they are even different manufacturers, just all ATI/AMD based GPU. I use Xinerama which is not great but a working solution. What do your X logs say after you enable Xinerama and reboot machine?

Comment: Here is the Xlog when i try to activate Xinerama : http://pastebin.com/L5EvDVub